# How to notify observer when an Object changes?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

**Short version: Is there a way to make sure an observer gets notified of a change, no matter what, even if Ember doesn't think a property has changed?**

In general, the ember observer pattern works for me, but here I'm stuck. I'm not sure if this is a bug or whatnot, or feature, but something about this bothers me.

I would be very happy with, in this occassion, some form of `myinstance.fireNotificationsNoMatterWhat("cache")`, but I can't find something like that in the code. Is there something I'm missing?

Sample code below showing the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>emberjs notification test</title>
        <!-- using current (at the time) version 0.9.5, from emberjs.com
             starter kit. -->
        <script src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="ember-0.9.5.min.js"></script>
        <script>
Test = Ember.Application.create({});

// I don't want an arrayproxy this time, and would be happy to find
// out if there is some form of ObjectProxy?
Test.cacheObject = Ember.Object.create({
    "cache": {},
    "add": function(key, value) {
        // In other situations, I don't need 
        // propertyWillChange/propertyDidChange, but here
        // I'm stuck, and I can't notify listeners when my
        // cache changes, so I figured I'd try out
        // these commands, which don't work, either.
        this.propertyWillChange("cache");

        var cache = this.get("cache");
        cache[key] = value;
        this.set("cache", cache);

        this.propertyDidChange("cache");
    },
});

// Contrived watcher.
Test.watcher = Ember.Object.create({
    // One of the many ways I've tried to bind to the
    // the object to get the observer to fire.
    "cacheBinding": "Test.cacheObject.cache",

    "obs": function() {
        // Ideally, whenever I call Test.cacheObject.add in different call
        // stacks I should be notified.
        console.log("cache has changed:");
        console.log(this.get("cache"));
    }.observes("cache"),
});

setTimeout(function() {
    // I get notified on the first add...
    Test.cacheObject.add("hello", "world");
}, 500);

setTimeout(function() {
    // ...but I will not get notified on the second, or any subsequent addition.
    Test.cacheObject.add("and", "universe");
}, 1000);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>emberjs notification test</h1>
        <h2>Please open your console to see the console.log output.</h2>        
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** It looks like there are short term fixes to this problem, however after trying out my own "fix", and trying out Roy's suggestion below, I think my core question will not be answerable until this [enhancement request](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/466) gets some love from the busy ember team. I can wait for that if it eventually gives me what the ArrayProxy gives me.

Answer (score 1):

Okay found the problem, and no it's not a bug. What's happening is the hash that `Test.cacheObject.cache` is set to is not changing. Basically you aren't changing the actual hash to another hash... you're just changing properties on the same hash in memory.

Take a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/ZJN4H/) for a solution, but short version, you only need to change `var cache = this.get("cache");` to `var cache = {};`

**edit:**

Since data must be perserved the only other thing I can think of is having cache be an array and just assigning it key/value pairs while observing `cache.@each`. I've updated the jsFiddle to show this. Hopefully this workaround works for what you're trying to accomplish.

**edit2:**

See the jsFiddle now. After sleeping a little I thought of a solution that satisfies all of your requirements. Oh and I don't believe in "no solution"... every problem has a solution!

Comment: If you notice in the example, I'm doing that. If you run the code, it doesn't work, or rather it works only once, ever. I'd be really happy to find out that my code is **wrong** and there is a solution right now, but I think, given what I've seen on github for ember, that I might have to wait for the ObjectProxy.

Comment: Hi ud3323, I should clarify, you're right, my code above doesn't explicitly try the static `Ember.propertyWillChange` and the `Ember.propertyDidChange`, rather it uses the instance methods. However, unfortunately, I have tried the static versions, and they don't work, either. Sad Face.

Comment: Sorry only read the short version. Didn't see a jsFiddle to run the code, but I'll make one for you. Give me a few minutes to review your code.

Comment: Hi ud3323. Thanks for the answer, but your answer essentially dumps any pre-existing data, which is not an answer. The cache that I need might have hundreds, even at some points thousands, of small objects referenced. Copying all of the referenced objects from object to new object instance every time I simply want to add a new key:value, or update an existing key with a new value, is unacceptable. What I was hoping for is some form of `myObject.notifyPropertyDidChange` that force-fires all listening observers, whether or not the underlying value has changed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8096/discussion-between-ud3323-and-jeremyosborne)

Comment: @jeremyosborne, it seems to me that your posted code is correct insofar as the Ember docs recommend.  The root of the issue appears to be that property(Will/Did)Change methods are not working as expected.  I've seen this problem in some of my work too.

Comment: @jeremyosborne (in case that chat thing is gone) I have a solution now that satisfies all of your requirements.

Comment: @rharper Thanks for the sanity check. I sometimes wonder if I'm just missing out on some pattern or whatnot that other people use to make everything work.

Comment: @ud3323, thanks for the answer. That is definitely an interesting approach. Let me try it out on Saturday after I have some spare time and compare it to the answer I created last night at about midnight.

Comment: @Roy Daniels, I tried this out, and while the answer "works" (thank you) It's not fundamentally what I was looking for. What I really want is something that can observe an object directly. This particular solution, while it works, is a lot like a solution that I came up with, and while I might sound nit-picky, I consider a kludge, not a solution. The solution appears to be: wait for the object proxy.